# How to retrieve boolean when given the String name of the boolean in Java

Tags: java

I want to be able to create a hashmap of Strings that will have entries like ("canSwim", "true") or ("canPickUpBoulders", "false"). I want to be able to target the object's perks boolean and then change those. I can set the pointer to point to a new boolean, but I can't set the perks boolean without getting them in the first place.

How can I select the perks boolean and change it.

```
//perks
boolean canPickUpBoulders,canRead,canSwim;

public boolean generateCharacter(HashMap<String,String> biasedMap)
{
    Iterator it = biasedMap.entrySet().iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){
            Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) it.next();
            //getBooleanClass andSet it to true;
            boolean theEntry = Boolean.getBoolean(pair.getKey().toString());
            theEntry = true;
            it.remove(); //avoidsConcurrentModificationException
        }
     return true;
}
```

The code is mostly an iterater that checks each entry in a hashmap and then should set the perks variables to whatever initialization that it has in the Key,Entry pair in the hashmap.

Comment: You're looking for Reflection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Reflection:

```
getClass().getField(pair.getKey()).setBoolean(this, theEntry);
```

EDIT: depending on your setup, you might set IsAccessable on the field first, or use getDeclaredField instead of getField

Comment: This works when I get the .toString on the getKey as well as put it inside a Try/Catch. Thanks!

Comment: yeah, i omitted all the nasty exceptions that might occour using reflection for readability and simplicity ...

Comment: And I'm just noticing, you might not have to call toString on key when you declare the variable it as Iterator<String> instead of just Iterator

Comment: I found an issue. If I do: getClass().getField(pair.getKey().toString()).setBoolean(this, theValue);... It will give me a noSuchFieldException on 'canSwim'...

Comment: this might happen if the field is private. Try to use getDeclaredField

Answer (score 0):

A Sample Code may useful to you...

```
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.util.Map;
    import java.util.Set;
    public class HelloWorld{

  public static void generateCharacter(HashMap<String,String> biasedMap)
  {
Set<String> keys = biasedMap.keySet();
    for(String key: keys){
        switch(biasedMap.get(key).toLowerCase()){
            case "true":
                System.out.println(biasedMap.get(key).toLowerCase().length());
                break;
            case "false":
                System.out.println(biasedMap.get(key).toLowerCase().length());
                break;
            default:
             System.out.println(biasedMap.get(key).toLowerCase().length());
                break;
        }

         System.out.println(biasedMap.get(key));
    }
 }
  public static void main(String []args){
    HashMap<String,String> biasedMap1 = new HashMap<String,String>();
    biasedMap1.put("canPickUpBoulders","false");
    biasedMap1.put("canRead","true");
    biasedMap1.put("canSwim","kj");
    HelloWorld.generateCharacter(biasedMap1);
   }
 }
```